# Event Listener not getting added to the div element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have following JavaScript code :

```
this._incrementButtonProperties = {  
        "enabled": this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.enabled,  
        "enabledClass" : "SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En",  
        "disabledClass" : "SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_Ds",  
        "appData" : this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.appData,  
        "text" : this.properties.incrementButtonConfig.text,  

        "incrementSelectCallback" : this._incrementButtonSelectHandler.bind(this),  
};
```

and

```
        this._incrementBtn = document.createElement('div');  
        this._incrementBtn .className = this._incrementButtonProperties.enabledClass;  
        this.divElt.appendChild(this._incrementBtn);
```

&

```
this._incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', this._incrementButtonProperties.incrementSelectCallback, false);
```

Also,

```
this._prototype._incrementButtonSelectHandler = function(ctrlRef, appData, params)  
{  

     // + & -  
     alert("_incrementButtonSelectHandler called... ");
}
```

But event listener is not getting added :-( If I write document.addEventListener('click', this._incrementButtonProperties.incrementSelectCallback, false); - then listener is getting added but I need it only for "this._incrementBtn" div element.

Any idea whats going wrong?

Note : Please do not suggest jQuery etc. I do not want to use any framework.

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: Maybe the order of lines is wrong. Can you construct jsfiddle to reproduce the problem so we can see it?

Comment: As far as I can see, it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/B5GEu/

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: alert("In _buttonHandlers..." + this._incrementBtn.className); - prints  SchedMainCtrlIncrementBtn_En so i do not think there is any prob in order

Answer (score 0):

Should it really read this._prototype._incrementButtonSelectHandler = ...?

Shouldn't it be this.prototype? Otherwise I don't see how this._incrementButtonSelectHandler could correspond to this._prototype._incrementButtonSelectHandler.

Also, you have a trailing comma in this._incrementButtonProperties {...}, which until Ecmascript 5 was actually invalid, even if most browsers will accept it without any complaining.

Comment: above changes had no effect!